# Not getting any returns in the Console

Tags: javascript, html

I am logging to console the `priceElement` and `quantityElement` but not getting any returns in the console.

I am not getting any returns from the `priceElement` and `quantityElement` in the console, I was expecting to get 799.99 from the `priceElement` and the value of 1 in the `quantityElement`. Please help how can I fix this

**Snippet**

```js
// The javascript

var removecartitembuttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-warning')
console.log(removecartitembuttons)
for (var i = 0; i < removecartitembuttons.length; i++) {
  var button = removecartitembuttons[i]
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    UpdateCartTotal()
  })
}

function UpdateCartTotal() {
  var CartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
  var CartRows = CartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
  for (var i = 0; i < CartRows.length; i++) {
    var CartRow = CartRows[i]
    var priceElement = CartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
    var quantityElement = CartRow.getElementsByClassName('checkout-input')[0]
    console.log(priceElement, quantityElement)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-items">
  <div class="cart-row">
    <div class="cart-item cart-column">
      <img class="checkout-cpu" src="Images/Cpu.jpg" width="100" height="100">
      <span class="checkout-item">CPU</span>
    </div>
    <span class="cart-column cart-price">$799.99</span>
    <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
      <input class="checkout-input" type="number" value="1">
      <button class="btn btn-warning" role="button">REMOVE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-total">
    <strong class="cart-sum">SUM</strong>
    <span class="cart-sum-amount">$800</span>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-checkout" role="button">Check Out</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure I understood your question fully - why are you removing the parent divs (they will not be available in the DOM any more once you remove them). But I see you are printing the 'elements' (div and text input) instead of their values/contents - maybe try printing the innetText/innerHTML for the div and 'value' for the text input. Something like 

`console.log(priceElement.innerText, quantityElement.value)`

See: https://jsfiddle.net/rcu4bn5t/1/ here (code to remove div is commented out)

Comment: You are removing the **cart-items** (`buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()`) element before you call the `UpdateCartTotal` function. This function tries to access elements that no longer exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your function before removing elements from button click.

Since you are calling the function after removing the elements, you are not getting anything in your console because everything get removed after button click.

```
var removecartitembuttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-warning')
console.log(removecartitembuttons)
for (var i = 0; i < removecartitembuttons.length; i++) {
  var button = removecartitembuttons[i]
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    UpdateCartTotal() //Call this function here!! before removing your elements from where you need to get data
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    
  })
}
```